# How to change Label text via Clock.schedule_interval

Tags: python, class, kivy

What is the right way to change test Label (using my_callback function) in code below:

```
class Hello(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Hello,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.Test = Label(text = "Aaa", pos=(0,0), font_size=70)
        self.add_widget(self.Test)

    def my_callback(self):
        print('My callback is called')
        self.Test.text = "Bbb"

    Clock.schedule_interval(my_callback, 3)

class app1(App):
    def build(self):
        return Hello()

if __name__=="__main__":
    app1().run()
```

Now there is error :

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'Test'

Probably there is something wrong with self call ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class Hello(FloatLayout):
    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        super(Hello,self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.Test = Label(text = "Aaa", pos=(0,0), font_size=70)
        self.add_widget(self.Test)
        Clock.schedule_interval(self.my_callback, 3)
    def my_callback(self, dt=0):
        print('My callback is called')
        self.Test.text = "Bbb"
```

you may want to take a look at some basic python tutorials before jumping right into kivy ...

Comment: Thanks Joran, You are right I catch up. I would add one thing in your code if you don't mind : my_callback should recive two arguments ;)